# I am trying to redirect after logining in angular. "Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'."

Tags: angular, typescript, authentication, firebase-authentication, angular-ui-router

here is my auth.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from "@angular/core";
import { GoogleAuthProvider } from 'firebase/auth';
import { AngularFireAuth } from '@angular/fire/compat/auth';
import { Observable } from "rxjs/internal/Observable";
import firebase from 'firebase/compat/app';
import { ActivatedRoute, Router, RouterLink, RouterStateSnapshot } from "@angular/router";
 



@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' }) 

export class AuthService {
  user$: Observable<firebase.User|null>;

  constructor(private afAuth:AngularFireAuth, private router:Router,private  route: ActivatedRoute) {
    this.user$ = afAuth.authState;
   }
  login() {
    let returnUrl = this.route.snapshot.queryParamMap.get('returnUrl') || '/';
    localStorage.setItem('returnUrl',returnUrl);
    this.afAuth.signInWithRedirect(new GoogleAuthProvider());
  }
  logout(){
    this.afAuth.signOut();
  }
 
}
```

and here is my app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { AuthService } from './auth.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(private auth : AuthService, router:Router){
    auth.user$.subscribe(user=>{
      if(user){
        let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl');
        router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl)
      }
    });
  }
  
}
```

and the error is coming for `router.navigateByUrl(returnUrl)` line for returnUrl, the error is
Argument of type 'string | null' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string | UrlTree'.
Type 'null' is not assignable to type 'string | UrlTree'.
I do not know how to solve this

Comment: It's pointing out that returnUrl might be null. What do you want to do if localStorage does not have a `returnUrl` string in it?

Comment: returnUrl  = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('returnUrl') || '{}');

Comment: @Stefani Totokotsopoulou: Since the return-value of `localStorage.getItem('returnUrl')` is most likely a string or null, I don't understand why `JSON.parse()` should be applied?

Comment: It might be string. It might not be string. Im not on your code. Try if works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because `localStorage.getItem('returnUrl')` returns either `string` or `null`,

the value of `returnUrl` is either `string` or `null`, but the `navigateByUrl` method doesn't accept `null` as a parameter.

so you need to set it, either way - a `string`, you can do it by giving it a default value:

```
let returnUrl = localStorage.getItem('returnUrl') || 'home-page';
```